# How to detect if a files are selected from file dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Shiboe/yuK3r/6/ I can do it without any problem. 
But,
I have got a multiple attribute in my input element and if i want to upload for example 8000 files catchEvent() function print out 0. Is any solution of this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#testInput").on('click', function(){
  run();
 });
 
 function run(){
  document.body.onfocus = catchEvent;
 }
 
 function catchEvent(){
  console.log(document.getElementById("testInput").files.length);
  document.body.onfocus = null;
 }
})
```

```html
<input id="testInput" type="file" name="test" multiple="multiple" />
```

Comment: Why do you listen for `focus` event? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can get file info as follow code:

```
godzilla.onchange= function(){
  var files = $(this)[0].files;
    if (files.length > 0){
       console.log("file selected="+files.length);
    }
};
```

Comment: It isn't a solution. If i'm uploading 8000 files i have to wait couple of seconds to get some value, otherwise i get null. I can do this:setTimeout(function () {
            console.log((<HTMLInputElement>$("#testInput")[0]).files.item(0));
        }
            , 1000);
        document.body.onfocus = null; but it isn't a solution... I want to display "loading" text when files are uploading that's why i find solution of this problem.

Comment: ok, but what if an user will click "cancel" in file dialog? onchange event won't perform.

Comment: Can i check if files are UPLOADING to input?(It would be perfect fit for me.) Your solution check if files are UPLOADED.